# Undefined Variable Request in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am having issues it says Request is undefined same goes for DB.

```
public function edit(Request $request,$id) {
        $name = $request->input('stud_name');
        DB::update('update student set name = ? where id = ?',[$name,$id]);
        echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";
        echo '<a href = "/edit-records">Click Here</a> to go back.';
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `use` statements that tell your script where to find these. Add

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

in your file after `namespace ...`

Comment: use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\UpdateUsers;

Comment: Not the DB one. And you didn't mention this in your question.

Comment: thanks I miss spelled Request as Requests.